# I can't seem to delete the simplest case on a Binary Search Tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I've posted about this last year because some university project and now I have to do it again (I never finished what I had to do last year). I've already looked at me previous code, all you guys answers on those questions, but still, I can't seem to understand this.

I'm not going to put all my questions in one long post, it just makes everything more confusing and I need to understand this once and for all.

I'm working with the simplest BST possible (just an integer for element) and I'm trying to delete a node from the tree in it's simplest cast, deleting a leaf.

The tree elements I'm testing with are inserted in the following order: `7 3 10 2 5 1 6 9 4 8`

And the output from in-order printing is, of course: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

This is my Tree structure:

```
typedef int TreeElement;

typedef struct sTree {
   TreeElement item;

   struct sTree *left;
   struct sTree *right;
} Tree;
```

And this is my delete function:

```
int delete(Tree **tree, TreeElement item) {
    if(!*tree) return 1;

    Tree *currPtr = *tree;
    Tree *prevPtr = NULL;

    while(currPtr) {
        if(item < currPtr->item) {
            prevPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->left;
        } else if(item > currPtr->item) {
            prevPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->right;
        } else {            
            if(!currPtr->left && !currPtr->right) {
                currPtr = NULL;
            }

            free(currPtr);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I can't understand why but this is not working... As far as I understand it, I'm searching for the element to delete correctly. When I find it, I check if this node is a leaf by checking the left and right child are "empty". Which they are for my test case (trying to delete node 1).

When try to delete node 1 with the code above, I'll still get the in-order printing as I posted above. If I remove the `currPtr = NULL` from the `if(!currPtr->left && !currPtr->right)` block, I'll get the following for the in-order printing: `0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

I'm not understanding any of this...

What I'm missing in the code above so I can correctly delete a node that is a leaf? This is the most simple case of deleting a node in a BST, yet, I'm having so much trouble doing it, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Sorry, I always forget the language tag :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you are change the value holding the current pointer, rather than the value in the node pointing to it.  What you would actually want is something like

```
int delete(Tree **tree, TreeElement item) {
if(!*tree) return 1;

Tree *currPtr = *tree;
Tree *prevPtr = NULL;
bool fromLeft = false;

while(currPtr) {
    if(item < currPtr->item) {
        prevPtr = currPtr;
        currPtr = currPtr->left;
        fromLeft = true;
    } else if(item > currPtr->item) {
        prevPtr = currPtr;
        currPtr = currPtr->right;
        fromLeft = false;
    } else {            
        if(!currPtr->left && !currPtr->right) {
            if( fromLeft )
               prevPtr->left = NULL;
            else
               prevPtr->right = NULL;
        }

        free(currPtr);

        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

Comment: I thought of doing that, but then I found this: http://e-hon.blogspot.com/2009/01/binary-tree-with-c.html And in that code (which I copied/compiled and it seemed to be working), there's no "fromLeft" variable and not even a pointer for the parent as I have in `prevPtr`. How is that code working?

Comment: He's using the original tree** to keep track of the active node, and dereferencing to compare.  So he is actually changing the parent node in a sneaky way.

Comment: No, either way is fine.  I find that mine is easier to see what's actually going on, but others see it better the other way.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree is a recursively defined data type, and deletion is far easiest with a recursive function.  I don't even want to *try* to debug your tricky iterative solution; the mistake you are making is not a minor code mistake; the mistake is that you are using the wrong ideas for the job.

Here is some *completely untested* code:

```
Tree *delete(item, tree) {
   if (tree == NULL)
     return tree;
   else if (item < tree->item)
     tree->left = delete(item, tree->left);
   else if (item > tree->item)
     tree->right = delete(item, tree->right);
   else { // here comes the only interesting case
     // if one child is NULL, move the other up
     // otherwise grab an item from one child and recurse
     Tree *answer;
     if (tree->right = NULL) {
       answer = tree->left;
       free(tree);
       return answer;
     } else if (tree->left == NULL) {
       answer = tree->right;
       free(tree);
       return answer;
     } else {
       tree->item = tree->left->item; // choice of left/right is     arbitrary
       tree->left = delete(tree->left->item, tree->left);
       return tree;
     }
   }
}
```